# What is diffrent between Silverlight and Windows Metro Style?

Tags: silverlight

I Dont Know About Metro Style Application I Want to convert my **silverlight** app in **Metro style** app so
plz Advice me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once again, this is all about framework.

- WPF is in the .NET framework.
- Silverlight is in the Silverlight framework (which is itself kind of a subset of the .NET framework).
- Modern UI (new name for Metro) is in the WinRT API

You could find interresting information about that on this blog: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/09/19/windows-8-what-s-new.aspx

To convert your Silverlight App to Modern UI App will be quite simple, especially if you wrote it using MVVM and C#/XAML. The only big constraint for modern UI is that you need Windows 8 and VS 2012 to program for it. The goal for you is to recompile your code in the Modern UI framework (Windows Store project in VS2012: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx), which will probably require a few code  modification (finally almost the same thing than if you try to recompile it in WPF with .NET).

[image]